# "Another of our backpacks" or "Another one of our backpacks"

Tags: expressions

I'm not sure which of the following two is correct:

1) "Another of our backpacks..."

2) "Another one of our backpacks..."

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct because '***another***' can be both an adjective and a pronoun.

If it is an adjective it is used with a noun (another backpack or another one of ...).
If it is a pronoun it is used alone (another of ...).

See the entry from Merriam-Webster's Dictionary
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/another:

***another***

*adjective*

1: different or distinct from the one first considered 
//  the same scene viewed from ***another*** 
angle

2: some other 
// do
 it ***another*** 
time

3: being one more in addition to one or more of the same kind
// have ***another***
 piece of pie

***another***

*pronoun*

: an additional one of the same kind,
one more

// one copy to send out, ***another*** 
for the files